# Não traz dado no Array Json no Android

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema em trazer dados para dentro de um Array em `Json`. Parece que ele não executa o Try catch, mas na variável resultado ele traz todos os dados. Gostaria de pegar o campo nome, mas ele não executa o Array.

Vejam o meu código:

#### PHP:

```
<?php //string json (array contendo 3 elementos) 

    $json_str = '{"empregados": '. '[{"nome":"Jason Jones", "idade":38, "sexo": "M"},'. '{"nome":"Ada Pascalina", "idade":35, "sexo": "F"},'. 

    '{"nome":"Delphino da Silva", "idade":26, "sexo": "M"}'. ']}'; 

    //faz o parsing da string, criando o array "empregados"
    $jsonObj = json_decode($json_str); 

    $empregados = $jsonObj->empregados; 

     //navega pelos elementos do array, imprimindo cada empregado 

    foreach ( $empregados as $e ) { 
         echo "nome: $e->nome - idade: $e->idade - sexo: $e->sexo<br>"; 
    } 
?>
```

#### JAVA:

```
public class retornaUsuario extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AcessoRest ar = new AcessoRest();
        String chamadaWS;
        chamadaWS = "http://www.cordeiro-it.com.br/SOUPROGRESSO/Ctrl/teste.php";
        String resultado = ar.chamadaGet(chamadaWS);
        Log.i("JSON:",resultado);

        JSONObject jsonResponse;
        try {
             ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
               jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resultado);
               JSONArray usuarios = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("empregados");
               System.out.println(usuarios);
               for(int i=0;i<usuarios.length();i++){
                   JSONObject usuario = usuarios.getJSONObject(i);
                   JSONArray characters = usuario.getJSONArray("nome");
                   for(int j=0;j<characters.length();j++){
                       temp.add(characters.getString(j));
                   }
               }
               Toast.makeText(this, "Json: "+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ERRO
            System.out.println("Erro ao retornar dados do usuário");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54607/discussion-on-question-by-felipe-nao-traz-dado-no-array-json-no-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP
$idades = array("Jason"=>38, "Ada"=>35, "Delphino"=>26);
$json_str = json_encode($idades); 
echo "$json_str";
?>
```

Testa com esse php.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AcessoRest ar = new AcessoRest();
        String chamadaWS;
        chamadaWS = "http://www.cordeiro-it.com.br/SOUPROGRESSO/Ctrl/teste.php";
        String resultado = ar.chamadaGet(chamadaWS);
        System.out.println(resultado);
        Log.i("JSON:",resultado);

        try {
            // Tratamento de erros
             JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resultado);
             JSONArray usuarios = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("empregados");

             for(int i=0; i < usuarios.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject jsonobject = usuarios.getJSONObject(i);
                 String nome   = jsonobject.getString("nome");
                 String cpf    = jsonobject.getString("cpf");
              }  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ERRO
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Erro ao retornar dados do usuário");
        }

    }
```